# Trying to get all records from 2 weeks ago

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to get all records from a table that were created 2 weeks ago.

My method looks like this:

```
 def getRecent(from: Instant): Future[Seq[User]] = {
    db.run(
      users.filter(f => f.status != 0 && f.createdAt > from ).sortBy(_.id.desc).result
    )
  }
```

I have an implicit already that I thought would work but I guess it is only for reading rows:

```
class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

    implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
      i => Timestamp.from(i),
      ts => {
        ts.toInstant

      }
    )

    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    ....
```

The error is:

```
 value > is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[java.time.Instant]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are nearly there. It is used for both read and writes. But here is the thing: **it needs to be in scope** (even for your filtering).

**Plain Slick solution**

Just put your conversion into companion object like this:

```
object UserTable {
    implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
      i => Timestamp.from(i),
      ts => {
        ts.toInstant

      }
    )
}
```

and then do this:

```
def getRecent(from: Instant): Future[Seq[User]] = {
    // I added this import here
    import UserTable.dateColumnType

    db.run(
      users.filter(f => f.status != 0 && f.createdAt > from ).sortBy(_.id.desc).result
    )
 }
```

**Play-Slick solution**

Above answer doesn't really fit `play-slick` part which is not explicitly stated in the question (though question is tagged with `playframework` tag). If you are using `play-slick` than your approach would be something like this:

Put your conversation into `trait` (`trait DbImplicits`) that require to be mixed-in together with or extends `HasDatabaseConfigProvider`.

```
trait DbImplicits { self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>
  import self.driver._

    implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
        i => Timestamp.from(i),
        ts => {
           ts.toInstant
        }
    )
}
```

Later use it like this:

```
class MyClassUsingImplicits @Inject()(
    protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider
) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] 
  with DbImplicits {
  import driver._

  // your further code comes here
}
```

EDIT: BTW I just noticed another mistake in this fragment:

```
f.status != 0
```

You should be using Slick operator:

```
f.status =!= 0
```

Comment: is that dateColumnType conversion typesafe, or can it throw an exception?

Comment: One doesn't necessarily exclude the other. You can create a conversion that would result in exception being thrown.
Existence of conversion in scope is verified on compile time - whether it's actual implementation will result in exception at runtime - that's another story.

Comment: @coolbreeze - sorry you asked about this `particular` conversion. Yeah - it shouldn't basically throw exceptions at runtime. It basically boils down to the question whether `Timestamp.from(i)` or `ts.toInstant` can throw exception in certain situations.

The whole point of this mappings (and Slick in general) is to be typesafe

Comment: i'm sure those methods will throw exceptions.  But at the same time you probably don't want your application to ignore those errors as it might corrupt data potentially so maybe crashing is good? :)

Comment: I think you are mixing two things:
- existence of these conversions is checked in compile-time (typesafety)
- these conversations may still yield exceptions at runtime (when the code is executed).

So, you like both situations *covered*. (kind of)