# Moving all implicits to a common object

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to move all of my implicits to a common object so I can use them in all of my DAO classes, but I cannot set it up correctly.

I have this so far:

```
package com.example.dao

import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.Instant

import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.db.slick.HasDatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

object DbImplicits {
  import driver.api._
  implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
    i => Timestamp.from(i),
    ts => {
      ts.toInstant

    }
  )
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
not found: object driver
```

Comment: Makes sense to me: I don't see object "driver" anywhere ... so, if I was a scala compiler, I would complain too :)

Comment: In my DAO I don't see it either, but it compiles.

Comment: Something must be different in your DAO then :/ Hard to guess what without seeing it though.

Comment: That question is actually not that silly as it's a common problem while using `play-slick`. It requires injected driver so it's not possible to just use `object`.

Answer (score 1):

In your DAO it's taken from extended trait `HasDatabaseConfigProvider`.

Just put your conversation into `trait` then (`trait DbImplicits`) that require to be mixed-in together with or extends `HasDatabaseConfigProvider`.

```
trait DbImplicits { self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>
  import self.driver._

    implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
        i => Timestamp.from(i),
        ts => {
           ts.toInstant
        }
    )
}
```

Later use it like this:

```
class MyClassUsingImplicits @Inject()(
    protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider
) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] 
  with DbImplicits {
  import driver._

  // your further code comes here
}
```

All this is kind of specific to `play-slick`.

I also updated the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41437295/2239369